# String Check on malicious SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

Im writing a simple utility that will allow our users to run simple select SQL statements on the DB to retrieve data they require. Just a textbox and a button and when they click the button it will spit out the query results in a list.

The problem I have is I only want them to be able to run SELECT statements. I dont want any edit statements to be executed i.e. update, insert, delete, drop etc.

Is there a simple way to parse a sql string to make sure its only a read only select statement entered?

Comment: You should check out [this](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-injection/sql-injection.php) to learn some preventive measures

Comment: It's dangerous to assume that `SELECT` statements are always safe.  `SELECT * FROM sys.tables` for example could give someone some rather dangerous information that they may be able to use elsewhere in your system.

Comment: Speaking of *simple* selects, it would be MUCH safer to create a simple query builder, letting users to select a table and a condition.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use sql permissions.  As a datareader, your users will only be able to SELECT.  `exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, <user>`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with this is by creating a user that only has limited permissions.

If you want to allow users to read data from all tables then you can go with what Steve D already suggested.

If you want to allow users to read data from only some tables but not all then you need to create a user that only has ‘public’ role and then GRANT SELECT for specific tables.

[image: login propertis]

Make sure user only has ‘public’ selected here for a given database

Then just execute this query for all tables

```
grant select on <schema>.<table> to <user>
```